# .htaccess rewriting $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following page:

```
mysite.com/news/index.php?tag=tag&name=name&id=id
```

I want to rewrite this so that it goes kind of as follows

```
mysite.com/news/tag/name-id
```

A full example of this would be.

```
foobar.com/news/apple/the-new-iphone-5-9001
```

Also after I rewrite this URL will I still be able to pull data as I would normally for instance:

```
$_GET['tag'] //would be apple
$_GET['name'] //would be the-new-iphone-5
$_GET['id'] //would be 9001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to .htaccess in your web root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/(.+?)-(\d+)/?$ /news/index.php?tag=$1&name=$2&id=$3
```